# How to align (up, down, right, left) stuff within a grid of Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a row with two equal columns (`.col-md-6`). The first column has a image. The second has a bit of text.

I want to align the second like this: `bottom:0; right:0`. In order to do that, I have to do `position: absolute;` on the second column and `position: relative` on the row. However, it works, but it doesn't flow correctly when the window becomes `sm`-small size. It will just squeeze together instead of forming two rows-not responsive.

This is my code:

```
<div class="row hidden-xs">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" style="max-width: 440px;" src="logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 0px; margin-right: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; bottom:0px">
        <p style="text-align: right;">a little bit of text. text. text</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have even tried adding `.col-md-offset-6` to the above. But I got this layout

```
000000000    
0       0
0       0
000000000
                000000
                0000000
```

I want this, and responsive, so when the window shrinks, the text makes its own row.

```
000000000    
0       0
0       0         000000
000000000        0000000
```

Notice the alignment, also.

I have tried and researched hours, but couldn't figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Do you get the same results using different browsers?

Comment: With postion relative / absolute seems to do what your are asking / saying, See: http://bootply.com/102390

Comment: @DanAndrews that just makes it lose its positioning. It just goes to the top-left corner of the column

Comment: @BassJobsen what you said I already tried. Look at the second paragraph

Comment: @jasonszhao, yes i read the second paragraph. But i don't see the problem you describe NOT in my bootply or i don't understand your problem.

Comment: it isn't responsive. When the window size is small, the two columns will just squeeze together, instead of forming two rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

The same could be achieved with `@media` in CSS.

---

**Original**

Thank you for your effort. I got it! I have to use javascript and this code is with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function window_size() {

        width=window.innerWidth
        || document.documentElement.clientWidth
        || document.body.clientWidth;

        height=window.innerHeight
        || document.documentElement.clientHeight
        || document.body.clientHeight;

        if(width<992) {
            $('.head-row').css('position', 'static');
            $('.text').css('position', 'relative');
        }
        else {
            $(".head-row").css("position", "relative");
            $(".text").css("position", "absolute");
        }


    };
    window_size();
    $(window).resize(window_size);  

});
```

This works perfectly.